# Why did kotlin drop the "new" keyword?

Tags: kotlin

Why did kotlin drop the **new** keyword ? 
It makes it harder to see the difference between a function call and an object allocation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Kotlin Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-style) clearly state that:

> - use of camelCase for names (and avoid underscore in names)
> - types start with upper case
> - methods and properties start with lower case

If you follow the above and **treat `constructor` as regular function** that can be called i.e. `val invoice = Invoice()` the `new` keyword becomes **redundant**. 
Once you accommodate yourself with the convention it's clear what a code is doing.

In fact even in Java code you'll have many *implicit* allocations that happen just beneath a method call like [`Collections.singleton(o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton(T)) or Guava's [`Lists.newArrayList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList()) so I don't think your argument about allocation visibility being better with the `new` keyword is fully valid.

Comment: By the way, it makes sense to set up syntax highlighting in IDE so that it will  highlight class names in *slightly* different color. It will make distinguishing constructor calls even easier.

Comment: totally new to kotlin, I would have like a meaningful KT compiler error like 'Don't need the 'new' keyword to create an instance through a constructor' instead of 'Unresolve reference:new', would have saved me a while

Comment: Any function with a `@Compose` annotation on it is also named like a type, to mirror the way that it sort of behaves like one. I guess one could extend that to factory methods for types as well. Then you get an _actual_ benefit of removing the `new` keyword - when you refactor constructors to/from factory methods, you don't have to update all the usages.

Answer (score 17):

(IMO) It was done because there is NO real difference between functions and object construction, i.e. nothing prevents a function to allocate an object (and they often do).

A good example is factory functions. These functions create new objects, but they are in no way class constructors.

AFAIK, the `new` keyword was created because of a negative experience with C\C++, where functions, returning new objects, have to be specially marked (by name conventions) in order not to forget to (manually) free the memory. In a auto-memory-managing language like Java\Kotlin it is not a concern.

Comment: In Java, a constructor _does not_ create an object. It just _constructs_ it. (The actual allocation of memory for the object, its creation, is essentially done by the `new`.) Presumably Kotlin's designers wanted to merge the two concepts to make them seem the same.

Answer (score 5):

Several other languages have no `new` keyword (Python, Scala, maybe Ceylon) and people who have switched to those languages never seem to miss it. I know I dont.

Comment: Scala has the `new` keyword. It is just that there are cases where you don't need to use it, like with case classes.

Comment: Oh, you're right. And, using companion objects, you can make the class invokable and have that redirect to the constructor, effectively eliminating the need for new. I'd seen that in my brief look into Scala, and had forgotten that it's not the norm.