# Kotlin make me crash! Is it a Function Or a Class when I read a code?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin, there are many omitted code with Kotlin. It make me crash when I read some sample code.

Such as `var map=HashMap()`

I can't judge what HashMap() is function or class. I have to judge it by Hint of Android Studio. Do you have a simple way?

If I use java, it will be different code style.

**Function:**  Map map=myFunction()

**Class:**      Class myClass=new Class()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889793/why-did-kotlin-drop-the-new-keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you follow Java naming conversion, class is PascalCase and function is camelCase.

Second, it does not matter. Creating a new object is just a constructor returning an object. It does not different from a a function return an object.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't judge what HashMap() is function or class

Don't think of this as `class` or `function`. `HashMap()` is a constructor which is really a method (function) that returns an instance of an object. So there is really no need of the `new` keyword here, and it make for clean code.

You can identify if it's a function or a constructor based on the Name itself (the case of the name).

Comment: Thanks! do you mean that the name of a function  and the name of a constructor  is different in Kotin  libary? such as class is PascalCase and function is camelCase.

Comment: The case is not enforced in Kotlin. It's the same as in Java. We need to name Classes starting with capital letter and Functions/Methods with a small letter. My point was constructor is a method and so we have a generic way to invoking a method, unlike java where we need to use `new` in front of constructor. Kotlin just removed this redundancy.